# Selenium click trouble (Python)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium (`ChromeDriver`) to automate a [chess site](https://www.chess.com/play/computer) but I am having trouble clicking on a piece and moving it. I have tried `click()` and `ActionChains` but nothing is working. Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

T = r"C:\Users\HP\Downloads\chromedriver.exe"
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
Driver = webdriver.Chrome(T, chrome_options=options)
Driver.get("https://www.chess.com/play/computer")
Driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="boardMessage"]/a').click()
Piece = WebDriverWait(Driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="chessboard_boardarea"]/img[22]')))
Piece.click()
```

When I run the script nothing happens but the white pawn should be highlighted in yellow. Can someone explain why `.click()` or `ActionChains` is not working? How can I make it work?

P.S. If solution requires JavaScript help, please write it in more detail because I don't know JavaScript at all.

Comment: Your code looks good to me. Can you try adding a small delay before the click?  `import time; time.sleep(1)`  before the last line

Comment: @Amit I add `time` before the last line and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is somewhat complicated. The chess pieces are `IMG`s that can be clicked but empty chess squares are not represented by an element. You will have to determine a coordinate system and use [`move_to_element_with_offset(to_element, xoffset, yoffset)`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains.move_to_element_with_offset) based off the board represented by `<div id="chessboard_boardarea" ...>` and the board labels A-H and 1-8. For `move_to_element_with_offset()`, the offsets are relative to the top-left corner of the element. So in this case, (0,0) is the top left corner of the chessboard.

The code below should click the white pawn at A2 and then click A3 which moves it. The board is 640px x 640px. Each square is 80px. The code is clicking in the middle of the square so:

- A8 would be 40,40
- A1 is 40,600
- H8 is 600,40
- H1 is 600,600

```
board = Driver.find_element_by_id("chessboard_boardarea")
action_chains = ActionChains(Driver)
action_chains.move_to_element_with_offset(board, 40, 520).click().perform() # A2
action_chains.move_to_element_with_offset(board, 40, 440).click().perform() # A3
```

You can determine what piece is represented by an element (`IMG` tag) by looking at the filename in the `src` attribute. For example, `src="//images.chesscomfiles.com/chess-themes/pieces/neo/80/bn.png"` has the filename `bn.png` and is the black knight. Each image filename will be two letters. The first letter is the piece color which is either 'b' for black or 'w' for white. The second letter is the piece name, 'p' pawn, 'r' rook, 'n' knight, 'b' bishop, 'q' queen, and 'k' king. So, `bn.png` is 'b' for black and 'n' for knight... the black knight.

You can determine where pieces are by using the `transform: translate(160px, 160px);` portion of the style attribute of the `IMG` tags representing the different pieces. For example, `transform: translate(160px, 160px);` this element is at 160,160 which is C6 (the coords are the top-left of the square and each square is 80px).

Comment: Its works ,but A2 square coordinates are (0,480).It is same to its translate.

Comment: Something went wrong and nothing happen when it click on A3.why Piece don't move,but stay on same position.

Comment: The translate coords for A2 are (0,480) but that is the top-left corner of the square. I would suggest clicking in the center of the square to be sure that you get the correct square.

Comment: I wrote and tested this whole thing in C# and it worked for me. I don't have python so I can't test it. You may need some brief pauses between clicks to make sure the browser has time to react?

Comment: Tried pauses between clicks and before finding board element, still not working.

Comment: I delete last two lines in my code and add this lines:                       `board = Driver.find_element_by_id("chessboard_boardarea")`\
`action_chains = ActionChains(Driver)`\
`time.sleep(1)`\
`action_chains.move_to_element_with_offset(board,560, 560).click().perform() # A2`\
`time.sleep(1)`\
`action_chains.move_to_element_with_offset(board,560, 480).click().perform()`\
`time.sleep(1)`\
`action_chains.move_to_element_with_offset(board,560, 400).click().perform()`\ .and it make move,but when I delete 3-4 lines it does't.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium Webdriver is not the right tool for it.

You could try [Genie automation tool](https://sourceforge.net/adobe/genie/wiki/Home/) if you are looking for a free tool. I've tried my hands on Genie, it's a bit complex but at the end it solves your problem.

Comment: Selenium works just fine. Why is Genie better in this case?

Comment: using coordinates based clicks would later result into failure with change in screen/resolution . Genie would generate IDs for you for each of those element.

Comment: There aren't elements on open squares.

Comment: You could also add a scaling function. You could get the size of the board and scale the coordinate system based on that. Anyway... just curious.

Comment: you are correct about the open squares, din't observe that earlier, just checked on pieces. I'll have to actually check  genie's behavior now. Thanks for bringing it to this point.