# How can I automate a Chess board with Selenium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, cpython, viewbox

There's a chess website I found (https://www.chess.com/play/computer), it's very confusing to work with on Selenium. The problem I'm encountering is that most squares are not actually treated as an element, it's only treated as an element if there's a piece on it or it's highlighted. This makes it very, very hard to work within Selenium as I cannot highlight a square without clicking it and to click it with Selenium I need the element.

Perhaps I could use a coordinates system as suggested here: [Selenium click trouble (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39757696/selenium-click-trouble-python) but their code was not functional as the post was five years old.

The board itself is a view box and each square that is an element has "square-" followed by a two-digit number in its class where the first digit is the numbers on the board and the second digit is the letters on the board converted to a digit. In the image I provided the exact class it has is "**highlight square-45**"

Thanks for any help!
[image: Demostrating the class ordering system]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a Javascript snippet via `driver.execute_script` to get the coordinates for each square on the board:

```
from selenium import webdriver
d = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver')
d.get('https://www.chess.com/play/computer')
board = d.execute_script('''
  function coords(elem){
      var n = elem.getBoundingClientRect()
      return {top:n.top, left:n.left, width:n.width, height:n.height}
  }
  var pieces = []
  for (var i = 1; i < 9; i++){
     if (i > 6 || i < 3){
        pieces.push(Array.from((new Array(8)).keys()).map(function(x){
           var square = document.querySelector(`.piece.square-${x+1}${i}`)
           return {...coords(square), piece:square.getAttribute('class').split(' ')[1]}
        }));
     }
     else{
        pieces.push(Array.from((new Array(8)).keys()).map(function(x){
           var arr = pieces[pieces.length-1]
           return {left:arr[x].left, top:arr[x].top - arr[x].height, 
             width:arr[x].width, height:arr[x].height, piece:null}
        }));
     }
  }
  return pieces
''')[::-1]
```

Output:

```
[[{'height': 62, 'left': 187, 'piece': 'br', 'top': 66, 'width': 62}, {'height': 62, 'left': 249, 'piece': 'bn', 'top': 66, 'width': 62}, {'height': 62, 'left': 311, 'piece': 'bb', 'top': 66, 'width': 62}, {'height': 62, 'left': 373, 'piece': 'bq', 'top': 66, 'width': 62}, {'height': 62, 'left': 435, 'piece': 'bk', 'top': 66, 'width': 62}, {'height': 62, 'left': 497, 'piece': 'bb', 'top': 66, 'width': 62}, {'height': 62, 'left': 559, 'piece': 'bn', 'top': 66, 'width': 62}, {'height': 62, 'left': 621, 'piece': 'br', 'top': 66, 'width': 62}], [{'height': 62, 'left': 187, 'piece': 'bp', 'top': 128, 'width': 62}, {'height': 62, 'left': 249, 'piece': 'bp', 'top': 128, 'width': 62}, {'height': 62, 'left': 311, 'piece': 'bp', 'top': 128, 'width': 62}, {'height': 62, 'left': 373, 'piece': 'bp', 'top': 128, 'width': 62}, {'height': 62, 'left': 435, 'piece': 'bp', 'top': 128, 'width': 62}, {'height': 62, 'left': 497, 'piece': 'bp', 'top': 128, 'width': 62}, {'height': 62, 'left': 559, 'piece': 'bp', 'top': 128, 'width': 62}, {'height': 62, 'left': 621, 'piece': 'bp', 'top': 128, 'width': 62}], [{'height': 62, 'left': 187, 'piece': None, 'top': 190, 'width': 62}, {'height': 62, 'left': 249, 'piece': None, 'top': 190, 'width': 62}, {'height': 62, 'left': 311, 'piece': None, 'top': 190, 'width': 62}, {'height': 62, 'left': 373, 'piece': None, 'top': 190, 'width': 62}, {'height': 62, 'left': 435, 'piece': None, 'top': 190, 'width': 62}, {'height': 62, 'left': 497, 'piece': None, 'top': 190, 'width': 62}, {'height': 62, 'left': 559, 'piece': None, 'top': 190, 'width': 62}, {'height': 62, 'left': 621, 'piece': None, 'top': 190, 'width': 62}], [{'height': 62, 'left': 187, 'piece': None, 'top': 252, 'width': 62}, {'height': 62, 'left': 249, 'piece': None, 'top': 252, 'width': 62}, {'height': 62, 'left': 311, 'piece': None, 'top': 252, 'width': 62}, {'height': 62, 'left': 373, 'piece': None, 'top': 252, 'width': 62}, {'height': 62, 'left': 435, 'piece': None, 'top': 252, 'width': 62}, {'height': 62, 'left': 497, 'piece': None, 'top': 252, 'width': 62}, {'height': 62, 'left': 559, 'piece': None, 'top': 252, 'width': 62}, {'height': 62, 'left': 621, 'piece': None, 'top': 252, 'width': 62}], [{'height': 62, 'left': 187, 'piece': None, 'top': 314, 'width': 62}, {'height': 62, 'left': 249, 'piece': None, 'top': 314, 'width': 62}, {'height': 62, 'left': 311, 'piece': None, 'top': 314, 'width': 62}, {'height': 62, 'left': 373, 'piece': None, 'top': 314, 'width': 62}, {'height': 62, 'left': 435, 'piece': None, 'top': 314, 'width': 62}, {'height': 62, 'left': 497, 'piece': None, 'top': 314, 'width': 62}, {'height': 62, 'left': 559, 'piece': None, 'top': 314, 'width': 62}, {'height': 62, 'left': 621, 'piece': None, 'top': 314, 'width': 62}], [{'height': 62, 'left': 187, 'piece': None, 'top': 376, 'width': 62}, {'height': 62, 'left': 249, 'piece': None, 'top': 376, 'width': 62}, {'height': 62, 'left': 311, 'piece': None, 'top': 376, 'width': 62}, {'height': 62, 'left': 373, 'piece': None, 'top': 376, 'width': 62}, {'height': 62, 'left': 435, 'piece': None, 'top': 376, 'width': 62}, {'height': 62, 'left': 497, 'piece': None, 'top': 376, 'width': 62}, {'height': 62, 'left': 559, 'piece': None, 'top': 376, 'width': 62}, {'height': 62, 'left': 621, 'piece': None, 'top': 376, 'width': 62}], [{'height': 62, 'left': 187, 'piece': 'wp', 'top': 438, 'width': 62}, {'height': 62, 'left': 249, 'piece': 'wp', 'top': 438, 'width': 62}, {'height': 62, 'left': 311, 'piece': 'wp', 'top': 438, 'width': 62}, {'height': 62, 'left': 373, 'piece': 'wp', 'top': 438, 'width': 62}, {'height': 62, 'left': 435, 'piece': 'wp', 'top': 438, 'width': 62}, {'height': 62, 'left': 497, 'piece': 'wp', 'top': 438, 'width': 62}, {'height': 62, 'left': 559, 'piece': 'wp', 'top': 438, 'width': 62}, {'height': 62, 'left': 621, 'piece': 'wp', 'top': 438, 'width': 62}], [{'height': 62, 'left': 187, 'piece': 'wr', 'top': 500, 'width': 62}, {'height': 62, 'left': 249, 'piece': 'wn', 'top': 500, 'width': 62}, {'height': 62, 'left': 311, 'piece': 'wb', 'top': 500, 'width': 62}, {'height': 62, 'left': 373, 'piece': 'wq', 'top': 500, 'width': 62}, {'height': 62, 'left': 435, 'piece': 'wk', 'top': 500, 'width': 62}, {'height': 62, 'left': 497, 'piece': 'wb', 'top': 500, 'width': 62}, {'height': 62, 'left': 559, 'piece': 'wn', 'top': 500, 'width': 62}, {'height': 62, 'left': 621, 'piece': 'wr', 'top': 500, 'width': 62}]]
```

Edit: clicking a square:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
def click_square(square):
   elem = d.execute_script('''return document.querySelector('body')''')
   ac = ActionChains(d)
   ac.move_to_element(elem).move_by_offset(square['left']+int(square['width']/2), square['top']+int(square['width']/2)).click().perform()

click_square(board[0][0])
```

Comment: Yes, but these are only the squares that have pieces on them. Other squares are not included in the output. If I want to move a piece from A to B I need the element of both squares or another approach.

Comment: @JustOscarJ No, `board` is storing the coordinates for every square, regardless of whether or not it is visible on the page as an element. For example, `board[2]` produces `[{'height': 62, 'left': 187, 'piece': None, 'top': 190, 'width': 62}, {'height': 62, 'left': 249, 'piece': None, 'top': 190, 'width': 62}, {'height': 62, 'left': 311, 'piece': None, 'top': 190, 'width': 62}, ...]`, the very first empty row after the black pawn positions.

Comment: How should I click at the positions? All I can find online is clicking at offsets of elements and stuff.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238036/discussion-between-justoscarj-and-ajax1234).